# Unable to display the number of buffers in query plan in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to anlayze a query in postgresql v9.6.4:

```
explain (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) SELECT p.*
FROM place as p INNER JOIN user as u ON p.id = u.place_id
where to_tsvector('simple', p.name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'a:*') and u.status = true;
```

The QueryPlan was :

```
Hash Join  (cost=20.28..31.72 rows=1 width=1561) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)'
Hash Cond: (u.place_id = p.id)'
->  Seq Scan on user u  (cost=0.00..11.20 rows=60 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)'
        Filter: status'
 ->  Hash  (cost=20.27..20.27 rows=1 width=1561) (never executed)'
       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on place p  (cost=16.01..20.27 rows=1 width=1561) (never executed)'
             Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, (name)::text) @@ '''a'':*'::tsquery)'
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on place_name_index  (cost=0.00..16.01 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)'
                    Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, (name)::text) @@ '''a'':*'::tsquery)'
Planning time: 0.118 ms
Execution time: 0.023 ms
```

I didn't get the number of read and hit buffers when I rexecute the query many times.How can I Fix that?

Comment: do other flags work? like format, timing or such

Comment: @VaoTsun I will try them now

Comment: @VaoTsun Itried format and it works but for timing and costs I got the same query plan as I got before.

Comment: `timing off`, cos it is on by default. but anyway - others work, and buffers ignored - right?..

Comment: yes. it's right.

Comment: Is this normal PostgreSQL? From where did you get the software?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm using pgAdmin4

Comment: I mean the server. Where did you download the server?

Comment: In a docker container.

Comment: I think that the problem with the key word JOIN because I changed the query and making simple joins without the key word `JOIN` and I got the buffers.